# How to sort out Deno errors with loading module?

Tags: visual-studio-code, deno

I tried to following in Deno Powershell: deno run --allow-net --unstable app.js, but I get always error: can't load the module. I also tried to practise using deno extension in VSCode, but when I chose Deno: Initialize workspace configuration and enable everything, I got an error message Deno project initialization failed. I have Deno version 1.15.2. What could possibly cause all these issues? Does it happen to Linux users too?

Comment: Manual reference: https://deno.land/manual@v1.16.0/vscode_deno

Comment: First: When running the command `deno --version` in PowerShell, do you see Deno version infomration printed to the console? If not, then Deno is not in your PATH and that needs to be addressed before moving forward. If so, are VS Code and the Deno extension both up to date? After confirming those things, when you run the initialization command in VS Code, what output do you see for the Deno extension? (You can find this by choosing View > Output, then select "Deno Language Server" in the dropdown menu in the Output view.

Comment: Thank you for the informative link. When I choose "Deno Language Server" It does say Connected to "Visual Studio Code" 1.62.1, language server initialized,
Server ready. Now I'm wondering if it has something to do with this "When enabled, the extension will disable the built-in vscode JavaScript and TypeScript language services, and will use the Deno language server instead." So to be on the safe side, maybe I should use the Powershell instead of VSCode. If I can get it working. I'm doing a web development assignments and we have to use deno.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.